# Log integral inequality

Tags: calculus, integral-inequality

Given

[image]

and

[image]

Show

[image]

Attempt:

$\int_{1}^{n}ln(x)dx = \int_{1}^{3/2}ln(x)dx+\int_{3/2}^{5/2}ln(x)dx+\int_{5/2}^{7/2}ln(x)dx+...+\int_{n-\frac{1}{2}}^{n}ln(x)dx$

$≤ \frac{1}{8}+ln(2)+ln(3)+...$

Comment: The limit at the last integrals should be $n$ not $n+1/2$

Comment: @ZiadFakhoury Ah yeah true, thanks